# Prevent parent page from scrolling when mouse is over embedded iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe, scroll, mousewheel

**...without limiting the scroll inside the iframe or the need to specifically name the scrollable elements.**

I have a google-map-like widget that can be embedded in 3rd party websites in the form of an iframe embed code. When people use mouse wheel over my widget I want only the content of the widget to scroll and not the parent page.

My question is similar to *[How to prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600454/how-to-prevent-page-scrolling-when-scrolling-a-div-element)* but my problem is that my ifrmae contains multiple elements including media and canvas that must keep listening to mouse wheel event. TLDR the solution to use **e.preventDefault()** and manually update the **scrollTop** property of all elements inside the iframe that should stay scrollable is impractical, error prone and dependent on the non-standard **wheelDelta** property.

[Here is a JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vuzeneqihu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) for your convenience. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While scrolling inside an `iframe`, the `body` doesn't know anything about what happens there. But when `iframe` scroller reach the bottom or the top, it pass scrolling to body.
See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qznujqjs/1/) and console log there.

Comment: that's very interesting solution, thanks for that, except as I said my widget is embedded in 3rd party pages over which I have zero influence, I can not ask them to add a script. I am going to explore if a solution with 2 nested iframes would solve the issue.

Comment: what if the iframe doesn't have any scrolling, the height and width is set as it's a part of the page ?