# Prevent parent page from scrolling when mouse is over embedded iframe in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, jquery-events, mousewheel

**...without limiting the scroll inside the iframe or the need to specifically name/tag all scrollable elements.**

Imagine google maps widget embedded in parent page. When you zoom in the widget you don't want the parent page to scroll, obviously.

I thought an answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486787/prevent-parent-page-from-scrolling-when-mouse-is-over-embedded-iframe) solved the problem:

> While scrolling inside an iframe, the body doesn't know anything about
>   what happens there. But when iframe scroller reach the bottom or the
>   top, it pass scrolling to body.
>
> Cancel the event that propagates from the iframe.

But the solution does not work in Firefox because Firefox will not - [by design](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1084121) - propagate events captured by iframe to the parent page, yet strangely it will scroll the parent page. See [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qznujqjs/1/).

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', onWheel);

function onWheel (e){
    if (e.target === iframe)
        e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
}
```

So, how do I prevent page from scrolling when user zooms content in embedded iframe, in Firefox?

Comment: Because Firefox uses the DOMMouseScroll event, I would try changing $('body') to  $(document), maybe it could work but Im not definetely sure. Worth a try

Comment: @GOSCHEN that is not the problem, "Firefox will not - by design - propagate events captured by iframe to the parent page"

Comment: If you can still capture the scroll event (on the parent page), maybe you can check the mouse position against the iframe position: if the mouse is inside, cancel the scrolling

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since it is a bug in Firefox, the workaround is to work directly with the `scroll` event, instead of the `mousewheel` / `DOMMouseScroll` ones.

The way I did: When user enters the mouse over the `iframe`, I set a flag to `true`, and when he leaves the mouse out there, I set it back to `false`.

Then, when user tries to scroll, but the mouse arrow is inside the iframe, I prevent the parent window scrolling. But, unfortunately, you can't prevent the window scrolling with the usual `e.preventDefault()` method, so we still need another workaround here, forcing the window to scroll exactly to the X and Y positions it was already before.

The full code:

```
(function(w) {
    var s = { insideIframe: false } 

    $(iframe).mouseenter(function() {
        s.insideIframe = true;
        s.scrollX = w.scrollX;
        s.scrollY = w.scrollY;
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        s.insideIframe = false;
    });

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if (s.insideIframe)
            w.scrollTo(s.scrollX, s.scrollY);
    });
})(window);
```

I've created an immediately executed function to prevent defining the `s` variable in the global scope.

Fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/qznujqjs/16/

---

#### Edit

Since your question was not tagged with jQuery (although inside it, you've showed a code using the library), the solution with vanilla JS is as simple as the above one:

```
(function(w) {
    var s = { insideIframe: false } 

    iframe.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        s.insideIframe = true;
        s.scrollX = w.scrollX;
        s.scrollY = w.scrollY;
    });
    
    iframe.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        s.insideIframe = false;
    });

    document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        if (s.insideIframe)
            w.scrollTo(s.scrollX, s.scrollY);
    });
})(window);
```

Comment: That's very elegant hack!

Comment: @Buzinas I want parent page to scroll even my mouse is on iframe but not happening in firefox, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/jop93dhr/2/

Comment: Thank's , this work very good ! =D and I has refactored a bit your first code but, i only changed how  to do the events.  I made them like this : `` $('my_container').on('mouseenter', 'iframe' ,function() {})´´

Answer (score 2):

Given all the prerequisites, I think the following is the sanest way to make this work in Firefox.

Wrap your `iframe` with a `div` which is a little bit shorter to enable vertical scrolling in it:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:190px; width:200px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
  <iframe id="iframeid" height="200px" width="200px" src="about:blank">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Now you can center the `iframe` vertically and re-position it every time 
the wrapper receives a `scroll` event (it will occur when a user tries to scroll away at frame edges):

```
var topOffset = 3;

wrapper.scrollTop(topOffset);

wrapper.on("scroll", function(e) {
    wrapper.scrollTop(topOffset);
});
```

Combine this with your previous fix for Chrome, and it should cover all major browsers. Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/o2tk05ab/5/

The only outstanding issue will be the visible vertical scrollbar on a wrapper `div`. There are several ways to go about it, for instance - [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

I think that will solve your problem 
it solved mine

```
    var myElem=function(event){
  return $(event.toElement).closest('.slimScrollDiv')
}

$(document).mouseover(function(e){
     window.isOnSub=myElem(e).length>0



})

$(document).on('mousewheel',function(e){
  if(window.isOnSub){  
console.log(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);      
    if( myElem(e).prop('scrollHeight')-myElem(e).scrollTop()<=myElem(e).height()&&(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta<0)){

      e.preventDefault()
    } 


}

})
```

replace '.slimScrollDiv' with the element selector you want to 
prevent parent scroll while your mouse is on it

http://jsbin.com/cutube/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I don't understand, this will prevent not only scrolling of the parent but also scrolling of the child. Can you eddit my JSFiddle and show me how your solution works? Thanks

Comment: thanks for your comment  please check my answer again I have edit it

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more clear, I have seen similar solution but it depends on the need to specifically name/tag elements that you want to be scrollable. Such approach is error prone and unscalable. I have put this as a condition in my original question but forgot to mention in this question again. I made an edit to mention it now.