# How to prevent original window from scrolling when iframe is open?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scroll

I have a iframe that loads on my website, but when you have scrolled to the top / bottom, the original window begins scrolling - I want to disable scrolling in the original window while the iframe is open.

I did a bit of research, but the closest i could get disabled scrolling in the iframe, not the original window.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211203/scrolling-child-div-scrolls-the-window-how-do-i-stop-that) You can replace the div with iframe when using any of the solutions in the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent parent page from scrolling when mouse is over embedded iframe in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165246/prevent-parent-page-from-scrolling-when-mouse-is-over-embedded-iframe-in-firefox)