# AngularJS: Prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV element

Tags: angularjs, scroll, scrollbar

### How to prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV element in **AngularJS**?

After reading this [**JQuery answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7600806/4467741) I want to apply the same in **AngularJS directive** but I don't know how... Any suggestions?

*Example in JQuery:* *http://jsfiddle.net/XNwbt/458/*

```
$( '.scrollable' ).bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
    var e0 = e.originalEvent,
    delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

    this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

*Thank you!*

---

### Edited:

I tried to do the same in AngularJS but the DIV element never is scrolling...

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('core')
    .directive('preventScrollBody', preventScrollBody);

function preventScrollBody() {
    return{
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
            var e0 = e.originalEvent,
                delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

            this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So juyst make directive customscroll and put this code to it link function. (replace $( '.scrollable' ) with element from args) should work imho

Comment: Just edited the question. I tried to do the same in Angular but doesn't work. (added the code in the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least work in my chrome:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
      console.log(e);
        var e0 = e;//.originalEvent,
        var delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

        this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sZFvgIyt9l9SZjQtTkH2?p=preview

Comment: Amazing! This works for me in plnkr, but I copied & pasted in my project and doesn't work. Maybe is for the Angular version? you are using Angular 1.4 and I'm using an old version of Angular 1.2... mmm I don't understand! hah! Thank you for all!

Comment: It's actually working but can you please explain Why you commented `//.originalEvent`?

Comment: Great, works perfectly! Just call prevent-scroll-body on the html element you want to apply it to :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Petr's great answer, I've replaced line

```
    var delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;
```

with

```
    var delta = e0.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;
```

and it works perfectly.
So modified function is

```
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {

        var e0 = e;
        var delta = e0.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

        this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
        e.preventDefault();
      });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

event argument "e" - which holds the scroll event object lets you prevent the page scroll, when it is scrolling on div ('.scrollable') as below

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I understand how works in JQuery. My question is how to do the same in angularJS directive