# Prevent page scrolling while scrolling a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have already found the solution in the accepted answer here:

[How to prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600454/how-to-prevent-page-scrolling-when-scrolling-a-div-element)

But want also to disable scrolling the main page on keys (when div content can't be scrollable anymore).

I'm trying to make something like this but it's not working:

```
$( '.div-scroll' ).bind( 'keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
                var e0 = e.originalEvent,
                delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

                this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;

                if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 12):

You can stop the scrolling of the whole page by doing:

**Method 1**

```
<div  onmouseover="document.body.style.overflow='hidden';"  onmouseout="document.body.style.overflow='auto';"></div>
```

but it makes the browser's scrollbar disappear whenever you hover over the div.

**Method 2**

Else you can look at jquery-mousewheel.

```
var toolbox = $('#toolbox'),
    height = toolbox.height(),
    scrollHeight = toolbox.get(0).scrollHeight;

toolbox.off("mousewheel").on("mousewheel", function (event) {
  var blockScrolling = this.scrollTop === scrollHeight - height && event.deltaY < 0 || this.scrollTop === 0 && event.deltaY > 0;
  return !blockScrolling;
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oz3CL7?p=preview)

**Method 3**

To stop the propagation with no plugins.

HTML

```
<div class="Scrollable">
  <!-- A bunch of HTML here which will create scrolling -->
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.Scrollable').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this),
        scrollTop = this.scrollTop,
        scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight,
        height = $this.height(),
        delta = (ev.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
            ev.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
            ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta),
        up = delta > 0;

    var prevent = function() {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

    if (!up && -delta > scrollHeight - height - scrollTop) {
        // Scrolling down, but this will take us past the bottom.
        $this.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
        return prevent();
    } else if (up && delta > scrollTop) {
        // Scrolling up, but this will take us past the top.
        $this.scrollTop(0);
        return prevent();
    }
});
```

**Method 4**

you can do it by canceling these interaction events:

Mouse & Touch scroll and Buttons associated with scrolling.

```
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to prevent keys scrolling but don't know how to incorporate this into the code I provided that only the .div-scroll element can use arrows to scroll and not the whole page where I'm in the bottom/top of the .div-scroll element and hit up/down arrow.

Comment: When the above method 4 is used, when the scrollable list reaches the bottom, the main / container div starts scrolling again, which seems like an odd thing, considering that no mouseout should've been triggered yet.

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind document to 'keydown' event like this:

```
$( document ).bind( 'keydown', function (e) { ... e.preventDefault(); }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to prevent keys scrolling but don't know how to incorporate this into the code I provided that only the .div-scroll element can use arrows to scroll and not the whole page where I'm in the bottom/top of the .div-scroll element and hit up/down arrow.

Answer (score 3):

This code block the scrolling by using keys:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 40) {
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to prevent keys scrolling but don't know how to incorporate this into the code I provided that only the .div-scroll element can use arrows to scroll and not the whole page where I'm in the bottom/top of the .div-scroll element and hit up/down arrow.