# Scroll only in notification div like facebook, not in body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to design notification like facebook. In facebook I see scroll in notification dropdown, but not scroll in body. Here is my screenshot of notification.

[image]

When i scroll in notification, body also move up and down. how can i stop this?
Please see my working fiddle
When i scroll in red area my hole body will scroll. but i want that, When i scroll in red area, then body will not scroll.

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;background-color:red;">
  test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br />
</div>
<div>
  test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br />
</div>
<div>
  test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br />
</div>
<div>
  test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br />
</div>
<div>
  test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br /> test
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good goal, what have you done to implement it? Stackoverflow is for asking questions about specific problems you are facing in your own code. Create [mcve] of the problem you are facing.

Comment: can you please post some code or give live example ?

Comment: Edited @Esko and

Comment: Edited @IsmailFarooq

Comment: so do you want to disable body scroll when user scrolling in the notification box right ?

Comment: I got my answer @IsmailFarooq Please check in answer list Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To get your notifications to scroll, you need to add `overflow-y: scroll` to your notifications element.

There are ways to stop the body from scrolling whenever this dropdown is open, but that seems like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`overflow-y: scroll`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) in CSS

Here's a working sample of what you are expecting to implement

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sahansera/5Lh1afk6/)

Hope this helps :)

PS - Don't use inline CSS in your production code though. It's just for *demonstration* purposes only

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer please check below code

```
$('.noscroll').on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) { 

  var e0 = e.originalEvent;
  var delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

  this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
  e.preventDefault();  
});
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awesome_designer/eu0smh4m/)

Comment: lol i was just posting this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7600806/2724173 but my PM had come :D

Comment: LOL :D :D bad luck. better luck next time. BTW thank you