# Prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV while resolving [Violation] warning in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modernizr, passive-event-listeners

At first this seems to be duplicate question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7600454/1292050) but there is more that need to be figured out.

How can I resolve below given `[Violation]` warning in google chrome console?

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
>   'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to
>   make the page more responsive.

Here is the code snippet that works but with the above mentioned `[Violation]` warning.

```js
$.fn.isolatedScroll = function() {
  this.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    let delta = e.wheelDelta || (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) || -e.detail,
      bottomOverflow = this.scrollTop + $(this).outerHeight() - this.scrollHeight >= 0,
      topOverflow = this.scrollTop <= 0;

    if ((delta < 0 && bottomOverflow) || (delta > 0 && topOverflow)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  return this;
};

$('.js-isolated-scroll').isolatedScroll()

// Nothing to check here as it's just repeating <p> tags
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
  for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
    copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
  }
}

multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.p-in-fixed'), 20, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.p-in-body'), 20, true);
```

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50%;
}
.fixed {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-isolated-scroll fixed">
  <p class="p-in-fixed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates.</p>
</div>

<p class="p-in-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates.</p>
```

Here is how I tried to fix it using Modernizr's `passiveeventlisteners` with this code `Modernizr.passiveeventlisteners ? {passive:true} : false` while following an answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721906/1292050). But I am getting this error message in console:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.

It's clear for me that I cannot using `e.preventDefault()` while using `{passive:true}` and that make sense, I just want know how can I Prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV while resolving [Violation] warning in console.

Here is the code snippet that doesn't work and produces above mentioned error in console.

```js
document.getElementById('fixed-content').addEventListener('wheel', avoidBodyScroll, Modernizr.passiveeventlisteners ? {passive:true} : false);
document.getElementById('fixed-content').addEventListener('mousewheel', avoidBodyScroll, Modernizr.passiveeventlisteners ? {passive:true} : false);
document.getElementById('fixed-content').addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', avoidBodyScroll, Modernizr.passiveeventlisteners ? {passive:true} : false);

function avoidBodyScroll(e) {
  let delta = e.wheelDelta || (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) || -e.detail,
    bottomOverflow = this.scrollTop + $(this).outerHeight() - this.scrollHeight >= 0,
    topOverflow = this.scrollTop <= 0;

  if ((delta < 0 && bottomOverflow) || (delta > 0 && topOverflow)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

// Nothing to check here as it's just repeating <p> tags
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
  for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
    copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
  }
}

multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.p-in-fixed'), 20, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.p-in-body'), 20, true);
```

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50%;
}
.fixed {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  /*! modernizr 3.5.0 (Custom Build) | MIT *
  * https://modernizr.com/download/?-passiveeventlisteners-setclasses !*/
  !function(e,n,s){function o(e,n){return typeof e===n}function a(){var e,n,s,a,t,f,l;for(var c in r)if(r.hasOwnProperty(c)){if(e=[],n=r[c],n.name&&(e.push(n.name.toLowerCase()),n.options&&n.options.aliases&&n.options.aliases.length))for(s=0;s<n.options.aliases.length;s++)e.push(n.options.aliases[s].toLowerCase());for(a=o(n.fn,"function")?n.fn():n.fn,t=0;t<e.length;t++)f=e[t],l=f.split("."),1===l.length?Modernizr[l[0]]=a:(!Modernizr[l[0]]||Modernizr[l[0]]instanceof Boolean||(Modernizr[l[0]]=new Boolean(Modernizr[l[0]])),Modernizr[l[0]][l[1]]=a),i.push((a?"":"no-")+l.join("-"))}}function t(e){var n=l.className,s=Modernizr._config.classPrefix||"";if(c&&(n=n.baseVal),Modernizr._config.enableJSClass){var o=new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+s+"no-js(\\s|$)");n=n.replace(o,"$1"+s+"js$2")}Modernizr._config.enableClasses&&(n+=" "+s+e.join(" "+s),c?l.className.baseVal=n:l.className=n)}var i=[],r=[],f={_version:"3.5.0",_config:{classPrefix:"",enableClasses:!0,enableJSClass:!0,usePrefixes:!0},_q:[],on:function(e,n){var s=this;setTimeout(function(){n(s[e])},0)},addTest:function(e,n,s){r.push({name:e,fn:n,options:s})},addAsyncTest:function(e){r.push({name:null,fn:e})}},Modernizr=function(){};Modernizr.prototype=f,Modernizr=new Modernizr,Modernizr.addTest("passiveeventlisteners",function(){var n=!1;try{var s=Object.defineProperty({},"passive",{get:function(){n=!0}});e.addEventListener("test",null,s)}catch(o){}return n});var l=n.documentElement,c="svg"===l.nodeName.toLowerCase();a(),t(i),delete f.addTest,delete f.addAsyncTest;for(var u=0;u<Modernizr._q.length;u++)Modernizr._q[u]();e.Modernizr=Modernizr}(window,document);
</script>

<div id="fixed-content" class="js-isolated-scroll fixed">
  <p class="p-in-fixed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates.</p>
</div>

<p class="p-in-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates.</p>
```

Or, Am I making things unnecessarily complicated because as it can be achieved just by using CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Update1:

This is a pure css option for webkit browsers using the `::-webkit-scrollbar` property.

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50%;
}
.fixed {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: calc(50% - 70px);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.fixed::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-isolated-scroll fixed">
  <p class="p-in-fixed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>

<p class="p-in-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Would something like this work? When you hover over the scrolling div, toggle a class on the body or other parent element that has an overflow of hidden, thus preventing parent scroll using CSS.

```js
$('.js-isolated-scroll').bind('mouseenter mouseleave touchstart touchend', 
function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("no-scroll"); 
});
```

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50%;
}
.fixed {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed-content" class="js-isolated-scroll fixed">
  <p class="p-in-fixed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus aliquam, beatae blanditiis, cum dicta earum eligendi esse eum inventore iusto molestiae necessitatibus nesciunt praesentium quod ratione, similique sit voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nisi molestiae expedita tenetur dolore, aliquam, quasi, ducimus neque exercitationem tempore maxime rerum! Alias tempora modi laborum animi voluptate minus quae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Comment: Cool :)
Now the only problem is that the content might shift a lot with the scrollbar disappearing, which is bad for the UX.

Comment: @Tomato as you pointed, content shifting is also one of the reasons I could not mark this as selected answer. Of course, the JS issue are not resolved.

Comment: Added an update for webkit based browsers using pure css to completely hide the scrollbar. Currently only works in Chrome, Safari, Opera, iOS Safari, Android Browser, and Chrome for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6zfn15w/1/).
The key trick in my answer is separating the two scrolls.
In your example, the body had the scroll so the fixed div had a container with scroll. By making a container element for the p-in-bodies which has the scroll, and placing the fixed-content outside of it, you can get around this.

HTML (added the container wrapper):

```
<div id="container">
  <p class="p-in-body">...</p>
</div>

<div id="fixed-content" class="fixed">
    <p class="p-in-fixed">...</p>
</div>
```

CSS (changed html, body & added #container):

```
html, body{
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.fixed {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}


#container{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have a situation where I cannot add anything out of container, of course it's kinda worth for upvote :) thanks you.